# CVPixelBuffer leak

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-leaks, avassetwriter

I create and use a CVPixelBuffer buffer like so :

```
            //Create buffer
            CVPixelBufferRef conversionBuffer = nil;
            if (indx < [self.sideImageList count] - 1)
            {
                UIImageView *tempImageView = [self.sideImageList objectAtIndex:indx + 1];
                CGRect originalBackgroundFrame = [tempImageView frame];
                UIView *tempView = [tempImageView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
                [tempView removeFromSuperview];
                tempImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
                [tempImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kVideoWidth, kVideoHeight)];

                UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageFromView:tempImageView];

                [tempImageView addSubview:tempView];
                tempImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
                [tempImageView setFrame:originalBackgroundFrame];

                UIImage *resizedBackground = [ICVideoViewController imageWithImage:backgroundImage 
                                                                      scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(kVideoWidth, kVideoHeight)];
                UIImage *appendedImage = [ICVideoViewController appendImage:resizedBackground
                                                                         to:conversionImage 
                                                                    atPoint:CGPointMake((kVideoWidth - conversionImage.size.width)/2,
                                                                                        (kVideoHeight - conversionImage.size.height)/2)
                                                                 otherPoint:CGPointZero];

                //Fill Buffer
                conversionBuffer = [ICVideoViewController pixelBufferFromCGImage:[appendedImage CGImage] size:CGSizeMake(kVideoWidth, kVideoHeight)];
            }
            else
            {
                //Fill buffer
                conversionBuffer = [ICVideoViewController pixelBufferFromCGImage:[conversionImage CGImage] size:CGSizeMake(kVideoWidth, kVideoHeight)];
            }
            while (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData==NO)
            {
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
            }
            if (indx == [self.sideImageList count] - 1)
            {
                break;
            }
            [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:conversionBuffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake((frameRate*i)+frames-1, frameRate)];

            while (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData==NO)
            {}
            //release buffer
            CVPixelBufferRelease(conversionBuffer);
```

and the method use to populate the buffer is .. i got this method from somewhere but there does'nt seem to be anything wrong with it ..

```
 + (CVPixelBufferRef) pixelBufferFromCGImage:(CGImageRef)image size:(CGSize)size
 {
 NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],     kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],  kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                         nil];
 CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;
 CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, size.width,
                                      size.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (CFDictionaryRef) options, 
                                      &pxbuffer);

 NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);
NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);

CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, size.width,
                                             size.height, 8, 4*size.width, rgbColorSpace, 
                                             kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
NSParameterAssert(context);



CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image), 
                                       CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
return pxbuffer;
 }
```

I seem to getting a leak in this method(courtesy leaks tool) and i still dont know what im doing wrong.

Comment: i have also released the adaptors buffer   - CVPixelBufferPoolRelease(adaptor.pixelBufferPool);

Comment: Nothing leaps out at me here, but it's possible that your AVAssetWriter or its AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor is leaking, causing the last pixel buffer it used to leak as well.

Comment: One suggestion I have is to use the AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor's CVPixelBufferPool and `CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer()` so that you don't have to recreate a new pixel buffer each time. That could reduce memory consumption and speed things up. Also, you'll really want to feed in your frames as BGRA instead of ARGB, because AVAssetWriter works much, much faster with BGRA sources.

Comment: This is really annoying that even when the CVPixelBuffer is released excusively and it's ref count goes down to zero it is not released by system somehow. Using a Pool does solve the issue.